# BigQuery is picking the wrong sheet when linking to Google sheet for table loading. What other options to use while loading?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Even if I give link to the second/third sheet in a group of Google sheets, it always picks the first sheet for loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery only supports reading from the first sheet/tab for now. There are ongoing work to read from any sheet.